# How big are copy on write pages in linux?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

We used RHEL 5.8 at my office. Our program relies on fork for parallelism. The application is very memory hungry (up to hundreds of GB) so we're relying on copy-on-write functionality to make this work. Lately we've been noticing some unexpectedly large number of shared pages and have narrowed the cause down to our memory manager. I'd like to understand how copy-on-write works in Linux better so I can come up with a solution.

- What is the page size in Linux? I assume it's 4k but just want to check.
- What is the page alignment? Our memory manager uses 4k pages too but is it possible we're out of alignment?

Answer (score 0):

This page will tell you how to look for mis allignment
with rhel 5 i think the chance is high that you have a mis allignment

http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Partition_Alignment

to find out the page size :
getconf PAGE_SIZE

Comment: This question is not about partitions.